# Load file from resource

Tags: android

To sum up: in order to add easily unit tests for a SAX parser I would like to load XML from a file.

Now, I have my XML in a static string inside my unit test class, but it is not very convenient for large XML.

This is why I would like to add some XML files to my project and load them in my unit test. How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is tagged as "Android" and I noticed that you mentioned an `Activity`, so I'm going to assume that you're trying to load an XML file within an Android application.  If that is the case, put your XML file under `/assets` and call:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("input.xml")
```

from your `Activity`.  From there, you can manipulate it into `SAXBuilder`.  This will only work if you've set up your test to run on the emulator (or if you're just trying to debug outside of a unit test).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it next monday when I'll be at the office.

Answer (score 1):

SAXBuilder has a constructor to read data from file:
 Document build(java.io.File file) 
           This builds a document from the supplied filename.
http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/input/SAXBuilder.html

Comment: Thanks, I did not know for this method of SAXBuilder

But my message was not clear, my problem is: I do not know what to do to obtain a File object from my xml file.

For instance when I call the fileList() method of my current activity context, I get an empty array.

Maybe I have to add some information in my Eclipse project in order to have access to this file from the application.

Comment: given your file is named input.xml and it is located in the current folder of your application, you can call:
Document doc = (new SAXBuilder()).build("input.xml");