# How to encrypt using a X509 public cert with Android?

Tags: java, android, encryption, x509

I am trying to encrypt a text file using a .pfx certificate file using :

```
public void EncryptUsingPublicKey(File in, File out, File publicKeyFile) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int)publicKeyFile.length()];
    new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile).read(encodedKey);

    // create public key
    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(in);
    Cipher pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    pkCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
    CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out), pkCipher);
    copy(is, os);
    os.close();
}
```

I have two problems:

1. Where should I store the .pfx file on the device?
2. Is this function correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that your code will work. PFX files are internally AFAIR PKCS#12 files with can contain multiple certificates and keys. The X509EncodedKeySpec you are using requires to have exactly one certificate in a .CER file (DER/binary format).

Therefore you have the following two options:

1. Extract the certificate from the PFX file as CER file (e.g. with the GUI tool [portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/)) or
2. Try to read the PFX file as a PKCS#12 KeyStore at it is presented here: [PKCS12 Java Keystore from CA and User certificate in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614239/pkcs12-java-keystore-from-ca-and-user-certificate-in-java)

In the end you can include the PFX/CER file as resource into your andoid app: [Load file from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851634/load-file-from-resource)

Comment: Thanks for this i will check out protecle.

Comment: I used portecle to expert the .cer (i choose Export > Head Certifcate and DER Encoded) and now get the error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad sequence size: 3

But X509CertificateStructure does nto seem to exists?

I have been reading this http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/J2ME-SubjectPublicKeyInfo-Bad-sequence-size-td1467139.html