# Integrate FusionChart in android application?

Tags: android, fusioncharts

I want to integrate fusionchart in android native application (not phonegap).I have write code for it as below

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
WebView webview =(WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
String summary = 
"<html>"+
"<head>        "+
" <title>My First chart using FusionCharts XT - Using JavaScript</title>      "+
"<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js\"></script>"+
"</head> "+  
"<body>"+     
" <div id=\"chartContainer\">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>"+          
"<script type=\"text/javascript\">"+
" var myChart = new FusionCharts( \"FusionCharts/Column3D.swf\",\"myChartId\", \"400\",\"300\", \"0\", \"1\" );"+
"myChart.setXMLUrl(\"Data.xml\");"+
"myChart.render(\"chartContainer\");"+      
"</script>"+      
"</body>"+ 
 "</html>";
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, summary, "text/html", "utf8", null);
}
```

please anybody tell me what is problem. I dont know how to give exact FusionCharts/FusionCharts.js path and no idea about Column3D.swf file.

Where can i get those files.

even this html code not working in my pc browser.

and I want to make bar chart in android application using only fusionchart !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to download the FusionCharts XT Download Package in order to receive the necessary JavaScript and SWF files, provided in the "Charts" folder of the Download Package, that would let you render FusionCharts. You may download the evaluation package from [here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/download/trials/).

Also, please check [**here**](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/?FirstChart/FirstChart.html) for the detailed process to create your first chart on the browser.

FusionCharts is expected to work perfectly on the native Android apps, provided all the other criteria mentioned [**here**](http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/tech-specs/) to render the JavaScript charts (Android 3.0 and above) and Flash charts are fulfilled.

FusionCharts does not have any native API to render the charts in Android apps. Hence, you would need to use some 3rd party mobile development framework like, PhoneGap, UIWebView, etc. and the API controls they provide, to achieve the same.

There is no sample for rendering FusionCharts in native Android apps, however, there is a similar implementation for iOS apps using UIWebView Control, which can be referred to with the help of this [**Blog post**](http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2012/02/create-charts-for-iphone-and-ipad-apps-using-fusioncharts-xt/).
[NOTE: This is purely as a reference and is not directly an Android implementation.]

Answer (score 0):

You can procure the SWF and JS files from FusionCharts XT pack. Trial download is available from http://www.fusioncharts.com/downloads. You will get these files from `Download Pack > Charts` folder.

Generally, you need to put these files in the `/assets` folder. These files get packed with the `apk`. You can access the files using the path - `/assets/...`.

> Reference: [Load file from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851634/load-file-from-resource)

Please remember that in case you are targeting Android v3+, you do not need to render Flash charts. Thus, you do not need to copy these `SWF` files. FusionCharts offers JavaScript (no Flash) charts, and your implementation gets simpler as detailed in the steps below:

1. Copy `FusionCharts.js`, `FusionCharts.HC.js`, `FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js` and `jquery.min.js` to required folder.

> However, include only `FusionCharts.js` in your HTML code. The other JavaScript files will be loaded automatically.

2. Instead of passing the name of the `SWF` file, pass the JavaScript alias of the chart. Required modification in your code:

   ```
   var myChart = new FusionCharts( \"Column3D\",\"myChartId\...
   ```

   `Column3D` is the alias of the chart you are trying to render. No need to prefix it with a path.
3. *DO NOT* load XML using `setXMLUrl`. FusionCharts uses ajax to load the XML data. Local Ajax is not supported (due to the security restrictions) in most of the browsers and it may fail. Instead, load the XML using Android's resource loading mechanism ([Load file from resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851634/load-file-from-resource)) and pass the data as String to the chart using `setXMLData` method.

   ```
   myChart.setXMLData(XMLLoadedAsString);
   ```

*MORE:* A more synced way is to implement this is to wrap the chart rendering JavaScript code inside FusionCharts's `ready` Event Listener as shown below:

```
    <script type=\"text/javascript\">"+

    " FusionCharts.addEventListener(\"ready\", function () { \n"+

    "     var myChart = new FusionCharts( \"FusionCharts/Column3D.swf\",\"myChartId\", \"400\",\"300\", \"0\", \"1\" );"+
    "    myChart.setXMLUrl(\"Data.xml\");"+
    "    myChart.render(\"chartContainer\");"+      

    "\n});"+
    "</script>"
```